# How do I place the elements of a list into the middle of another list? A one dimensional battleship game. (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list

So I'm creating this simple little battleship program.  I'm getting a little frustrated at the aspect of a player placing their boats.  What I'd like is for the function ship_place() to take a boat as a parameter, ask for the index of the array the player would like to place the boat, and then place the boat in the ocean starting at the specified index.  I want the contents of the boat (which is a list) to be "exported" to the ocean (which is also a list).

I created this function and it's been giving me two errors.  The first is that for some reason it's placing the entire boat array into the specified index.  The second is that the list taken_spots1 is not receiving all of the taken spots it should be.

P.S. I originally had for loops within the function but was getting the same error, so I tried while loops to see if anything would change.  Nothing did.

```
ocean = ['O']*100
taken_spots1 = []
boat1 = ['<','>'],
boat2 = ['<','=','>'],
boat3 = ['<','::','>'],
boat4 = ['<','@','@','>'], #cannons
boat5 = ['<','G','U','N','>']
ship_yard = [boat1,boat2,boat3,boat4,boat5]

def ship_place(boat):
    spot = ""
    while spot == "":
        spot = input("Place a boat: ")
        spot = eval(spot)
        if spot in taken_spots1:
            spot = ""
            print("That spot's already taken, dummy")
        else:
            j=0
            while j < len(boat):
                taken_spots1.append(spot + j)
                j += 1

    i = 0
    while i < len(boat):
        ocean[spot - 1 + i] = boat[i]
        i += 1


for i in range(5):
    ship_place(ship_yard[i])
    print(ocean)
    print(taken_spots1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is almost correct!  The problem is that you have some extra commas after some of the boats.

For example:

```
boat1 = ['<','>'],
```

Remove the comma.

It is a little bit surprising, but in Python when you add a comma, you get a "tuple".  Usually we see tuples written like this:

```
t = (1, 3)
```

That would be a length-2 tuple with the values `1` and `3`.  But you can declare a length-1 tuple and it is legal:

```
t = (1,)
```

And it turns out that the parentheses are not required:

```
t = 1,
```

This is what you did.  You declared a length-1 tuple, whose contents were a list.  Then when your function received its argument, `boat`, it received a length-1 tuple, and when it indexed the tuple it got a list.

P.S. You can do what you want using "slicing".  When you slice a list, you specify some section of it; if you assign to that section, you replace that section.

You put a ship into the ocean with this loop:

```
i = 0
while i < len(boat):
    ocean[spot - 1 + i] = boat[i]
    i += 1
```

You can replace the loop with this code:

```
start = spot - 1
end = start + len(boat)
ocean[start:end] = boat
```

You can even make a one-liner but I think it is too hard to read and understand.

```
ocean[spot-1:spot-1+len(boat)] = boat
```

P.P.S.  If I were writing this program, I wouldn't maintain the `taken_spots` list as well as the `ocean`.  I would just look in the ocean to see if there is already a boat there.  Right now you could potentially have a problem where the `taken_spots` isn't accurate; the ocean is always what it is, so looking at it removes a potential source of bugs.

Here is one way you could look at the ocean to see if a ship will fit in a spot.

```
def spot_taken(i, ship):
    start = i
    end = i + len(ship)
    for ch in ocean[start:end]:
        if ch != 'O':
            return True
    return False
```

If you are just starting out with Python, you may not have learned about the `any()` and `all()` functions... but they provide a very convenient way to write `spot_taken()`.  Like this:

```
def spot_taken(i, ship):
    start = i
    end = i + len(ship)
    return any(ch != 'O' for ch in ocean[start:end])
```

You could even make it a one-liner, but again maybe it's too ugly:

```
def spot_taken(i, ship):
    return any(ch != 'O' for ch in ocean[i:i+len(ship)])
```

If this seems too weird or tricky, ignore it for now.  You will learn it eventually.  But `any()` and `all()` are among my favorite features in Python, so I just wanted to share them with you!

P.P.P.S. It is often useful, when debugging, to add calls to `print()` and make sure that values are what you expect.  When I printed the value of `boat` it printed as a tuple: `(['<', '>'],)`  And that was how I figured this out.

It can also be handy to have a debugger that lets you inspect variables, check their types, etc. without needing to write the `print()` statements.  I have used WingWare IDE, which has a free-to-use version that you might want to check out.  http://wingware.com/

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.  But do you have any idea why my code doesn't work?

Comment: UGH! I spent about an hour messing with the for loops and stuff and all it is is a few commas left over from earlier.  I should have known when the 5th boat worked and the others didn't.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay there we go, this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin python

ocean = ['O']*100
taken_spots1 = set()
boat1 = ['[<','>]']
boat2 = ['[<','=','>]']
boat3 = ['[<','::','>]']
boat4 = ['[<','@','@','>]'] #cannons
boat5 = ['[<','G','U','N','>]']
ship_yard = [boat1,boat2,boat3,boat4,boat5]

def foundboatpart(start, boatlen):
    for t in range(start, start + boatlen):
        if t in taken_spots1 or t > len(ocean) or t <= 0: return 1
    return 0


def ship_place(boat):
    spot = ""
    while spot == "":
        spot = int(input("Place a boat: "))
        if foundboatpart(spot, len(boat)):
            spot = ""
            print("That spot's already taken, dummy")
        else:
            taken_spots1.update(range(spot, spot + len(boat)))

    ocean[spot - 1 : spot + len(boat) - 1] = boat


for i in range(5):
    ship_place(ship_yard[i])
    print(ocean)
    print(taken_spots1)
```

**Sample run**:

```
Place a boat: 1
['[<', '>]', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
{1, 2}
Place a boat: 2
That spot's already taken, dummy
Place a boat: 3
['[<', '>]', '[<', '=', '>]', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Place a boat: 6
['[<', '>]', '[<', '=', '>]', '[<', '::', '>]', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
Place a boat: 8
That spot's already taken, dummy
Place a boat: 9
['[<', '>]', '[<', '=', '>]', '[<', '::', '>]', '[<', '@', '@', '>]', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
Place a boat: 12
That spot's already taken, dummy
Place a boat: 13
['[<', '>]', '[<', '=', '>]', '[<', '::', '>]', '[<', '@', '@', '>]', '[<', 'G', 'U', 'N', '>]', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}
```